# Click() on <input type="file" /> not opening file dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i am making a chrome extension, when i click on the input of type file programmatically this warning appears but when i do it in the chrome console it opens the file dialog.

[image: Warning in console which click from extension]

i have tried both of these ways

```
document.querySelectorAll('.text-xs-center.font-weight-bold.file-upload-center-table')[0].click()
```

and

```
document.querySelectorAll('.text-xs-center.font-weight-bold.file-upload-center-table')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click', { bubbles: true }));
```

Both them works in console but when with extension the warning appears

Comment: The Browser is saying that you need a user action to use `Element.click()` on an input type file. So, that would need to wrapped in some other user Event... like the click of some other button.

Comment: The error says that this input can only be clicked by a physical user. It works in console because devtools emulates physical user interaction. The only theoretically possible method for extensions to do it is to use `chrome.debugger` API and [Input](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/) CDP commands but that will show a warning in the entire browser.

Comment: @StackSlave i tried... but wrapping it in some user event didnt worked.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you simplify it a little more, how to carry the procedure you suggested.
and why it happens on some specific sites but for others it works

Comment: The error happens only when there wasn't any physical interaction with the user first ([source](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/forms/file_input_type.cc;l=163;drc=90e1213a3d33cc29ae5c6f1e8fac205361fd4fbf)). If the user clicked or pressed a key inside this page (or frame) prior to your code then it will work. Regarding code, look for examples yourself, I won't do it as it requires testing.